# Vulkan buffer/image bound to device-local-memory without transfer-dst-flag

Tags: vulkan

- let **mem** be a `VkMemory` created with `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` set
- let **dst** be a `VkImage` or `VkBuffer` bound to **mem**

The only way to insert data into **dst** seems to be using the respective `VkCmdCopy`-commands to copy from a `VkBuffer`/`VkImage` which is bound to host-visible memory.

For this copy to succeed, **dst** also needs to be created with `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT` or `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT` respectively.

I wonder: 
What are the use-cases, if any, to create a `VkBuffer`/`VkImage` that is bound to device-local memory, without setting the respective `TRANSFER_DST`-flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example a depth buffer does not necessarily need to be copied into.